# When both halves of an OR regex group match, is it defined which will be chosen?

Tags: java, regex

I've run the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(asd|asdf).*");
    Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile("(asdf|asd).*");
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher("asdf");
    Matcher m2 = pattern2.matcher("asdf");
    if (m.matches()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
    if (m2.matches()) {
        System.out.println(m2.group(1));
    }
}
```

And I get the following output:

*asd*

*asdf*

It seems as though the left hand side of the OR group is chosen in cases when both match. However, I haven't been able to find this behaviour documented. Does anyone know if the behaviour is defined?

Comment: Do you have details of where that's defined? Thanks

Comment: I cannot link to any source, but since regex tries to match as less as possible, I think this observation is applicable. If you say "first" instead "left", this makes even more sense.

Answer (score 4):

In non-POSIX regex flavors (as in Java, as [***The `Pattern` engine performs traditional NFA-based matching with ordered alternation as occurs in Perl 5***](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#jcc)), the first alternative is matched. In POSIX, the longest alternative is matched.

See what [Perl help](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Matching-this-or-that) says about alternation:

> To match `dog` or `cat`, we form the regexp `dog|cat`. As before, Perl will try to match the regexp at the earliest possible point in the string. At each character position, Perl will first try to match the first alternative, `dog`. If `dog` doesn't match, Perl will then try the next alternative, `cat`. If `cat` doesn't match either, then the match fails and Perl moves to the next position in the string.

See the [*Alternation with The Vertical Bar or Pipe Symbol* at regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) that describes NFA-compliant alternation behavior:

> **The order of the alternatives matters.** Suppose you want to use a regex to match a list of function names in a programming language: `Get`, `GetValue`, `Set` or `SetValue`. The obvious solution is `Get|GetValue|Set|SetValue`.
>
> The regex engine starts at the first token in the regex, `G`, and at the first character in the string, `S`. The match fails. However, the regex engine studied the entire regular expression before starting. So it knows that this regular expression uses alternation, and that the entire regex has not failed yet. So it continues with the second option, being the second `G` in the regex. The match fails again. The next token is the first `S` in the regex. The match succeeds, and the engine continues with the next character in the string, as well as the next token in the regex. The next token in the regex is the `e` after the `S` that just successfully matched. `e` matches `e`. The next token, `t` matches `t`.
>
> At this point, the third option in the alternation has been successfully matched. Because the regex engine is eager, it considers the entire alternation to have been successfully matched as soon as one of the options has. In this example, there are no other tokens in the regex outside the alternation, so the entire regex has successfully matched `Set` in `SetValue`.

And then:

> But **the POSIX standard does mandate that the longest match be returned**, even when a regex-directed engine is used. Such an engine cannot be eager. It has to continue trying all alternatives even after a match is found, in order to find the longest one.

However, the order of alternatives may be irrelevant *if* the context on either side is strictly defined. If you use anchors, `^(asd|asdf)$`, to match the *full string*, you will only get the one that corresponds to the right alternative.

Comment: Not refuting this claim, but do you have a source for this?

Comment: @ohaal It's [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html). Scroll to **POSIX Requires The Longest Match**

Comment: .* matches any character (except newline)

    Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed

Comment: @Tushar: I was adding that to the answer.

Comment: Thanks that's a useful link. It would be reassuring to see something in java's documentation saying that this is how *their* implementation behaves though!

Comment: @user1675642: Java [regex documentation says](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/intro.html) that its regex syntax is a version of a Perl regex syntax. So, it is NFA, and follows the non-POSIX rules when it comes to alternation handling.

Comment: I believe I furnished enough documentation proof of why and how regex alternation works in Java. Even if it is not stated directly that Java uses the first alternative if matched and does not check the following ones it still provides reference to those sources.