# regex: "(^|)" vs "(|^)"

Tags: regex, r

I have a very special question concerning regular expressions in R:

```
grepl("(|^)over","stackoverflow")
# [1] TRUE

grepl("(^|)over","stackoverflow")
# [1] FALSE

grepl("(^|x|)over","stackoverflow")
# [1] FALSE

grepl("(x|^|)over","stackoverflow")
# [1] FALSE

grepl("(x||^)over","stackoverflow")
# [1] TRUE
```

Why do not all those expressions evaluate to `TRUE`?

Comment: not sure about why for the default library (POSIX 1003.2 extended regular expressions) but works as expected with pcre `grepl("(^|)over","stackoverflow", perl = TRUE)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

POSIX regular expressions actually *should* make all those True. It appears that [R uses a slightly modified version](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/a2a71d238eb144f158aebf2eda4cbc01095ea91a/src/extra/tre/tre-parse.c) of [Ville Laurikari's TRE library](https://github.com/laurikari/tre) that doesn't quite follow the standard. I'd follow @rawr's recommendations and use `perl = TRUE` for more compliant regular expressions.

See also: [When both halves of an OR regex group match, is it defined which will be chosen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34946091/when-both-halves-of-an-or-regex-group-match-is-it-defined-which-will-be-chosen)

Comment: R uses the TRE implementation of POSIX ERE by default and PERL-type by option.: https://github.com/laurikari/tre